# Select same point features from two different datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

I am completing an update to an address database and have 76 point features that I would like to cross-reference with the old database to perform a quality check on. What would be the most efficient way of selecting the features in the old database based on the highlighted ones in the new one? I've tried select by location, but this produces more results than I need.

Each point has an object_id, a business_id, and attributes that are virtually the same.

Comment: Please provide more info - object_id or attributes that are unique?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the geometries are equal between both datasets.

One way of doing this would be with a bit of SQL (studies are your tables in this exemple). Syntax may vary from one DB system from another (Oracle vs. PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT UNIQUE (s1.id), s2.id
 FROM STUDIES s1, STUDIES s2
 WHERE st_equals (s1.shape, s2.shape) = 1
 AND s1.id <> s2.id;
```

There is also in the same way a function in geometry API ArcGIS to check if 2 geoms are equal:

```
geom1.equals(geom2)
```

Documentation for ArcGIS

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-equals.htm
https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm look for equals

On a side note, you may want to use a tolerance and not exact equal beetween geometries ...